# Haskell - pattern matching syntactic sugar and where

Tags: haskell

Often I have a function of such pattern:

```
f :: a -> b
f x = case x of
  ... -> g ...
  ... -> g ...
  ...
  ... -> g ...
  where g = ...
```

There is an syntactic sugar for *almost* this case:

```
f :: a -> b
f ... = g ...
f ... = g ...
...
f ... = g ...
```

Unfortunately I can't attach my `where` to it: I'll obviously get bunch of `not in scope`s.
I can make `g` a separate function, but it's not nice: my module's namespace will be polluted with utility functions.
Is there any workaround?

Comment: You don't have to export `g`, thus the namespace pollution is only a problem *within* your own module.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think that your first example isn't bad at all. The only syntactic weight is `case x of`, plus `->` instead of `=`; the latter is offset by the fact that you can omit the function name for each clause. Indeed, even dflemstr's proposed `go` helper function is syntactically heavier.

Admittedly, it's slightly inconsistent compared to the normal function clause syntax, but this is probably a good thing: it more precisely visually delimits the scope in which `x` is available.

Comment: The equational syntax for defining functions does seem like kind of an unnecessary gimmick.

Answer (score 11):

No, there is no workaround. When you have multiple clauses for a function like that, they cannot share a `where`-clause. Your only option is to use a case statement, or do something like this:

```
f x =
  go x
  where
    go ... = g ...
    go ... = g ...
    g = ...
```

...if you *really* want to use a function form for some reason.

Answer (score 6):

```
f = g . h  -- h is most of your original f
  where h ... = ...
        h ... = ...
        g =
```

Comment: I think the OP was looking for a general solution to the problem where `g` might appear anywhere on the RHS of any of the equations (or not at all).

Comment: Yeah, I felt the question was ambiguous and gave an answer for the case that hadn't already been answered.

Answer (score 5):

From Haskell 2010 on, or with GHC you can also do:

```
f x 
    | m1 <- x = g
    | m2 <- x = g
    ...
    where g =
```

but note that you cannot use the variables bound in the patterns in `g`. It's equivalent to:

```
f x = let g = ... in case () of
     () -> case x of 
          m1 -> g
          _  -> case x of
              m2 -> g
              ....
```

Answer (score 3):

Your original solution seems to be the best and only workaround. Syntactically it's not any heavier than direct pattern matching on function parameters if not even lighter.

But just in case if what you need is just to check preconditions and not pattern match don't forget about guards, which allow you to access the `where` scope freely. But really I see nothing bad in your `case of` solution.

```
f :: a -> b
f a
  | a == 2    = ...
  | isThree a = ...
  | a >= 4    = ...
  | otherwise = ...
  where isThree x = x == 3
```

Answer (score 2):

With `LambdaCase`, you can also do this:

```
{-# language LambdaCase #-}

f :: a -> b
f = \case
  ... -> g ...
  ... -> g ...
  ...
  ... -> g ...
  where g = ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it safe to assume that you consistently use `g` on most, if not all, of the different branches of the case statement?

Operating with the assumption that `f :: a -> b` for some `a` and `b` (possibly polymorphic), `g` is necessarily some function of the form `c -> d`, which means that there *must* be a way to consistently extract a `c` out of an `a`. Call that `getC :: a -> c`. In that case, the solution would be to simply use `h . g . getC` for all cases, where `h :: d -> b`.

But suppose you *can't* always get the `c` out of an `a`. Perhaps `a` is of the form `f c`, where `f` is a `Functor`? Then you could `fmap g :: f c -> f d`, and then somehow transform `f d` into a `b`.

Just sort of rambling here, but `fmap` was the first thing that came to mind when I saw that you appeared to be applying `g` on every branch.